# Neo4j formatting timestamp() epoch to datetime without using apoc plugin

Tags: datetime, neo4j, timestamp, cypher, string-formatting

Is there a way in Neo4j to format epoch value saved using timestamp() function as "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'" without using the apoc plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the datetime features of Neo4J to do this. Example below:

```
RETURN datetime({ epochSeconds:1562735372 }) AS theDate
```

Or using the timestamp()

```
RETURN datetime({ epochSeconds:timestamp()/ 1000, nanosecond: 23 }) AS theDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not know if this might be useful for somebody but I ended using:

```
datetime({ epochSeconds:toInteger(VALUE)})
```

Since using the alternative proposed by Avenger789 was throwing an error.